# Reset every networking parameter in Linux Mint

Tags: networking, linux-mint, ethernet

I have linux mint cinnamon running on a laptop. I moved and connected to an ethernet network in a students resident, so I do not have admin access to the network. It was an unstable connection, I tried to change some configs to make it better, but I made it worse. Now my PC wont even recognize that the cable is plugged in.

When I go to the IT Office we connect the computer and it works.

When I boot Mint from a USB, it connects and works perfectly.

I would like to know: **How can I "factory reset" all the network configuration of Linux Mint?** Including network interfaces, everything related to networking, I wanted clean new, given that it works when I boot from usb.

Thanks

Comment: duplicated of https://askubuntu.com/questions/637637/how-to-reset-network-manager-to-default ?

Comment: I like @solsTiCe 's response